# Magento Admin-User Panel Nav Bar disabled

Tags: php, mysql, magento

[image: Admin Navigation Bar]

The Admin and User panel navigation bar as shown in the image above is displaying very well but the links are not there i.e. `<a href="#">`

> I cannot access my panel anymore.

Question is

1. What caused it?

> [My guess : Magento Clear Cache]

2. How to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in your browser when viewing that page ?

Comment: The links of the navigation bar is either stored in XML files or DB, I have a backup and as there are too many products updated, looking for some help on which table-row or XML file the {{links}} is stored.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about magento, so i'm not much help.

Comment: Came to a point, guessing `core_url_rewrite` contains the required paths of links